# How to make a cURL request to phpcodechecker?

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm trying to use phpcodechecker.com by using cURL.
A sample request would look like this:

```
http://phpcodechecker.com/api/?code=$hello;
```

My output always returns `null`.
Does it have anything to do with how I pass the code parameter?

```
$code = "
    function test($string){
        return $string ;
    }
";


$url = "http://phpcodechecker.com/api/";


$request_headers = array(
    "code:" . base64_encode($code),
    'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); // Might need this, but I was able to verify it works without
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');

$data = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    exit();
}

$json = json_decode($data, true);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($json);
```

> API documentation
>
> Submit code to the API by GET or POST with variable name: code
>
> Example (no errors): http://phpcodechecker.com/api/?code=$hello;
>
> You can base64_encode() and then urlencode() when using POST, just
> pass http://phpcodechecker.com/api/?base64 in your request url or body
> content

Comment: Ok, but do you have a question of a problem to ask about

Comment: Yes, the return value is null. a JSON is expected.

Comment: You should probably create the string with single quotes instead of double-quotes, or else it's going to try to parse out `$string`

Comment: In the curl code you appear to be putting `$code` into the headers, rather than the query parameters (as it is in your sample request URL). Not sure why you're doing that. Do you understand the basic anatomy of a HTTP request? e.g. URL, query parameters, header, body, etc?

Comment: You're getting `null` because `$data` is not json. It's returning the HTML of the website

Comment: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-curl-get-request-with-parameters-exampleexample.html

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
$code = '
    function test($string){
        return error_here;
    }
';


$ch = curl_init();

$url = "http://phpcodechecker.com/api/";
$dataArray = ['code' => base64_encode($code)];

$data = http_build_query($dataArray);

$getUrl = $url."?".$data;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $getUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 80);
   
$response = curl_exec($ch);
    
if(curl_error($ch)){
    echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}else{
    echo $response;
}
   
curl_close($ch);
```